# vertical centering div in relative div with min-height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an absolute positioned div inside a Bootstrap column (relative positioned) neither the absolute div or the column have a defined height. However the column div has a min-height of 400px.

html

```
<section class="row row-eq-height"> 
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="section-content">
           ... content ...
        </div>
     </div>

     <div class="col-sm-6 section-img">
        ... full cover image ...
    </div>
 </div>
```

css

```
   @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

  .section-content { position: absolute; }

  .section-img { min-height: 400px; }

  .row-eq-height {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 400px;
   }
```

When the screen in 768px the .section-content div goes on-top on the .section-img div. The height of the column is generated by the min-height put on the .section-img.
I'm trying to vertically center the .section-content inside the column/.section-img.
//////

Comment: please include working sample

Comment: problem is all the content is all dynamic and brought in through wordpress. Essentially I need to center a absolute div inside a relative div both withouts defined heights

Comment: have you tried using `top:0; bottom: 0; margin: auto;`?

Comment: I have tried that, but without a defined height, that doesn't work

Comment: how about creating another container inside of it and display it as `table` and display `table-cell` for the content?

Comment: I was hoping that I wuldn't have to use tables, I was asking to see what options were available since margin, top ... etc wasn't applicable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use tables. And if I understand you correctly, as Rob stated, create an inner wrapper and set the display property for the parent container to `table` and inner wrapper to `table-cell` with `vertical-align: middle;`

```
<div class="col-sm-6 section-img">
  <div class="middle">... full cover image ...</div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS

```
.section-img {
  min-height: 400px;
  display: table;
}
.middle {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the section-content div isn't inside the section-img div. I have Bootstrap columns turn full width in 768px screens so I made the content div absolute so it sits on-top the image (on large screen they are beside each other). One problem I had was that Without a min-height on the image div it wouldn't show. I use flex and row-eq-height to center it on larger screens and make them the same size (so the image shows)